# MVC Event User Online Accessing Specific HLS Video Streaming

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, http-live-streaming

I may have several HLS streaming video address. I'd like to have a real time event telling any change of how many user online who access each of the streaming file.

User no need to pass in login page. They may retrieve the video streaming url directly and put into their player.

How do I accomplish this task in MVC?

Answer (score 0):

If you allow them to play the URL in their own player, you'll need software on the media server that's creating the HLS streams to keep track of it for you.

If you were providing users with a web page that had a player on it, and not giving them the URL directly, you would just need to count how many people are on the page, and you wouldn't have to worry about the video at all.